# Open documents, ppt and excel sheets directly into google docs/driver

Tags: default-programs, presentation, word-documents

I do not want to use libreoffice and not able to find lightweight alternative for excel and ppt viewers.

So could you please tell me how can trick nautilus to open these files directly into google docs/drive using my default browser.

[nautilus-gdoc](http://code.google.com/p/nautilus-gdoc/) seems to add this functionality, but it can not open it seemlessly. i.e. double clicking does not take me to browser and open the document.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an option from OMGUbuntu:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/gwoffice-integrates-google-docs-with-the-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.